# relative javascript issues for ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

We are using relative paths to load js file thorough ajax.
I can see all Js files are loading absolutely fine.
But, js files can't able to see Debuggers in any browsers. 
Like in firefox browser, If I use FireBug and trying to see our JS
we couldn't see js files. But I'm pretty sure Js files loading once we hit any page.
If I use absolute path, Js files are loading.
As per requirement, we shouldn't use absolute paths.
Please give suggestions

Answer (score 0):

One option.  Use absolute paths when debugging.  Switch to relative paths for final testing and deployment.  It's common to change a number of things between the debug environment and final test/production (like minimizing the code).

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome and Firefox debuggers (or any others that I know of) won't show dynamically loaded javascript.  It doesn't have to do with what path you use to load them, those browsers just don't have that functionality yet.

Here's one kind of snooty article talking about it: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626140637/http://www.almaden.ibm.com/u/bartonjj/fireclipse/test/DynLoadTest/WebContent/DynamicJavascriptErrors.htm)

And here's an example of one of the open bugs filed on it for firefox/firebug: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2912